# How to check how long specific entry in arp table will stay and when it'll be expired?

Tags: networking, arp

I know how to setup how long arp entry are cached. But - how to check how long specific entry will stay in arp table, and when next arp request will be made or arp entry disapear from table/ change status from REACHABLE to STALE?

Comment: i've found partial answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372011/configuring-arp-age-timeout/15511117#15511117 - ip -s n show when ip was lastly communicated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to find time when is, some kind of log, arp table populated with new entry.

You can run `tcpdump` and watch or you can install `arpwatch` and see.

Arp table is writen to `/proc/net/arp`.

Time when some entry will be deleted from arp table depends of `base_reachable_time` and `gc_interval`. In most cases after some entry is added to arp table, after last communication and last live packet start `base_reachable_time`. When this time expired without new packets mac address change status. On that time system start to count `gc_interval` time aka if some entry is no used garbage collector will delete them but only if ...

To long story. You can not find exactly time from add action and also can not known exact time of deletion from arp table.